# Haar Matrix is orthogonal

Tags: fourier-analysis, linear-transformations, signal-processing, wavelets

How can I prove that Haar Matrix is orthogonal ($H_{2^n}$ for all $n$)? $H_1,H_2,H_4,H_8, \dots, H_{2^n}, \dots$

Comment: Are we all supposed to know what a Haar matrix is?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that Haar Matrix is famous. You can find the definition here: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/Haar/index.html

Comment: By induction${}$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please edit your post and add the definition of the Haar matrix and explain your attempts at solving this problem?